# Operação com 2 colunas dinamicamente

Tags: r, dplyr, dinâmico

Seja o data frame

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
a  x  2  1  4
b  y  4  3  5
c  z  6  5  6
```

Calcular, por exemplo:
p1=v3+v4
p2=v4+v5
é trivial, pois posso fazer isso para cada um manualmente, então teria:

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 p1 p2
a  x  2  1  4  3  5
b  y  4  3  5  7  8
c  z  6  5  6  11 11
```

Agora, imagina que esse arquivo tenha 1000 colunas! Como fazer isso dinamicamente, isto é, gerar p1, p2, p3, ..., p100 ?

Comment: Sempre a começar em `v3`, na terceira coluna?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seguinte código faz o que a pergunta pede.
Utiliza só R base e creio que não depende do data frame a processar.

Primeiro um data frame para teste.

```
set.seed(4961)    # Torna os resultados reprodutíveis

m <- 5
n <- 10
dados <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(100, m*n, TRUE), m, n))
colnames(dados) <- paste0("v", seq_len(ncol(dados)))
```

Agora define-se uma função que soma as colunas duas a duas a começar na coluna do argumento `from`.

```
soma2cols <- function(DF, from = 3, prefix = "p"){
  nc <- ncol(DF)
  stopifnot(nc >= from)
  cols <- seq_len(nc)[-seq_len(from)]
  res <- sapply(cols, function(i) DF[[i - 1]] + DF[[i]])
  colnames(res) <- paste0(prefix, seq_len(ncol(res)))
  res
}

soma2cols(dados)
#      p1  p2  p3  p4  p5  p6  p7
#[1,] 153 100 100 180 130  72  76
#[2,]  74  70  45  79 118 135  87
#[3,] 112 104  69 139 143 125 119
#[4,] 156 103  84 141  90 109 161
#[5,]  26 101 175 153 108  99  91

result <- cbind(dados, soma2cols(dados))

result
#  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10  p1  p2  p3  p4  p5  p6  p7
#1 44  9 69 84 16 84 96 34 38  38 153 100 100 180 130  72  76
#2 68 61  5 69  1 44 35 83 52  35  74  70  45  79 118 135  87
#3  5 69 28 84 20 49 90 53 72  47 112 104  69 139 143 125 119
#4 95 84 74 82 21 63 78 12 97  64 156 103  84 141  90 109 161
#5 52 77  4 22 79 96 57 51 48  43  26 101 175 153 108  99  91
```

Comment: obrigado pela rapidez! Funcionou :) Você saberia reproduzir o mesmo resultado com DPLYR?

Comment: @user2725174 Creio que não ou, pelo menos, levaria mais tempo.